# background overly pseudo z-index

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Hello** I've tried to create background-color overlay using pseudo element but the problem that the inner content like h2 (in this example) will be under the background overlay, I know that I can give h2 position relative and z-index but I was ask if there are a way let me to write less codes:

```css
.breadCrumbs{
    width:100%;
    padding:20px 0;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-04/149189733741781.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
.breadCrumbs:after{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.60);
}
.breadCrumbs h2{
    margin-bottom:30px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="breadCrumbs text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h2>Contact</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="pages.html">Pages</a></li>
                        <li>Contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `before` instead of `after`.

```css
.breadCrumbs{
    width:100%;
    padding:20px 0;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-04/149189733741781.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
.breadCrumbs:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.60);
    
}
.breadCrumbs h2{
    margin-bottom:30px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="breadCrumbs text-center">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h2>Contact</h2>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="pages.html">Pages</a></li>
                        <li>Contact</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this:

```css
.breadCrumbs{
    width:100%;
    padding:20px 0;
    position:relative;
    background-image:url('http://store6.up-00.com/2017-04/149189733741781.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
}
.breadCrumbs h2{
    margin-bottom:30px;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-size:40px;
}
.bg {
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.60);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="breadCrumbs text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="bg"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <h2>Contact</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="pages.html">Pages</a></li>
                    <li>Contact</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

There are also some other solutions but they are more error prone by old browsers.